# How to select exact sentence from MYSQL

Tags: mysql

> I have two coloumns:
>
> ```html
> > 
> >     <table border=1>
> >       <tr>
> >         <td><b>Phrase</b></td>
> >         <td><b>Sentence</b></td>
> >         </tr>
> >       <tr>
> >         <td>Love Math</td>
> >         <td>I really love math</td>
> >         </tr>
> >      </table>
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> Using the Query below:
>
> > SELECT sentence FROM tbl_sentence WHERE MATCH(phrase) AGAINST('
> >     love math')
> >
> > `OUTPUT: "I really love math"`
>
> MY Problem is when the user input only the word "love".
>
> Still gets the output "I really love math".
>
> How to return nothing if the user only input "I Love".

Comment: are you sure you even want to be using fulltext search ?

Comment: Why shouldn't they get "I really love math" when they type "love"?

Comment: I'm trying to create an AI chatbot.
What I want with my search query is when the user input a sentence like:
User input:  "I want to say that I hate you."

in my database table it has a data: "I hate you"
all i wanted is to get the part of the sentence. Like the Phrase "I hate you" to match with my table data.

Answer (score 0):

This should bring up the result for "I Love":

```
SELECT
`sentence`
FROM
`tbl_sentence`
WHERE
`tbl_sentence`
LIKE
"%I%Love%";
```

The problem is, you have to change the user's input to replace spaces with the wildcard "%" character.

If you want it to NOT bring up a result for "I Love", use only 2 wildcard characters, surrounding the whole phrase:

```
SELECT
`sentence`
FROM
`tbl_sentence`
WHERE
`tbl_sentence`
LIKE
"%I Love%";
```

Comment: I'm trying to create an AI chatbot.
What I want with my search query is when the user input a sentence like:
User input:  "I want to say that I hate you."

in my database table it has a data: "I hate you"
all i wanted is to get the part of the sentence. Like the Phrase "I hate you" to match with my table data.